# Selecting random words from table

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have the following basic MySQL data:

```
CREATE TABLE my_words (my_word VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO my_words VALUES ('dog');
INSERT INTO my_words VALUES ('cat');
INSERT INTO my_words VALUES ('tree');
INSERT INTO my_words VALUES ('ball');
INSERT INTO my_words VALUES ('life');
INSERT INTO my_words VALUES ('complex');
INSERT INTO my_words VALUES ('digeridoo');
INSERT INTO my_words VALUES ('hamster');
INSERT INTO my_words VALUES ('it');
INSERT INTO my_words VALUES ('house');
INSERT INTO my_words VALUES ('love');
INSERT INTO my_words VALUES ('zealous');
INSERT INTO my_words VALUES ('nevis');
INSERT INTO my_words VALUES ('mountain');
INSERT INTO my_words VALUES ('call');
INSERT INTO my_words VALUES ('nail');
INSERT INTO my_words VALUES ('rat');
INSERT INTO my_words VALUES ('hat');

SELECT CONCAT(w1.my_word, w2.my_word) joined
FROM my_words w1, my_words w2
WHERE LENGTH(CONCAT(w1.my_word, w2.my_word)) = 8
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

I can write the SQL statement at the end to generate a list of 5 random concatenated strings made up of 2 words, where the total length of the string is 8 characters.

That works fine for a simple table of data like I've got in the sample.

However, the "real" table I am working with contains about 6,200 lines.

If I try the same type of statement it takes 10 seconds to generate the 5 strings.

I guess the SQL is very inefficient as it is searching through the table twice each time and those tables aren't joined in any way.

I wondered if there is a simpler way to extract strings of words made up of 2 words from the table, where the length of the concatenated string is 8 characters long (though that can change - I'm just using 8 as an example).

Thanks

---

**Update 1**

Explain Plan of:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT CONCAT(w1.fld_un, w2.fld_un) joined
FROM j_un w1
JOIN j_un w2 ON w1.fld_len = 8 - w2.fld_len
WHERE w2.fld_len < 8
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5;

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      w2      range   un_len          un_len  5   \N      2694        Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      w1      ref     un_len          un_len  5   func    527         Using where
```

---

**Update 2**

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the "fld_un" table has about 6,200 rows.

The "word" is held in the "fld_un" column.

The structure of the table is:

```
Field       Type            Null    Key     Default     Extra
fld_id      int(11)         NO      PRI     NULL        auto_increment
fld_un      varchar(255)    YES             NULL     
fld_cat_id  int(11)         YES     MUL     NULL     
fld_len     int(2)          NO      MUL     NULL
```

These indexes exist on the table:

```
Keyname     Type    Cardinality Field
PRIMARY     PRIMARY 6318        fld_id
cat         INDEX   15          fld_cat_id
bob         INDEX   11          fld_len
```

Does it matter that there is already a primary index on the table? I don't technically need that I suppose.

Statement:

```
SELECT CONCAT(word1, word2) joined
FROM (
    SELECT w1.fld_un word1, w2.fld_un word2
    FROM j_un2 w1
    JOIN j_un2 w2 ON w1.fld_len = 8 - w2.fld_len
    WHERE w2.fld_len < 8
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 5) x;
```

Query took 23.6805 sec

Explain Plan:

```
id  select_type     table       type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY         <derived2>  ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL        NULL    5    
2   DERIVED         w2          range   bob             bob     4           NULL    4627    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED         w1          ref     bob             bob     4           func    527     Using where
```

When I revise the "bob" index to include 2 columns as suggested by Thorsten Kettner:

```
Keyname     Type    Cardinality Field
bob         INDEX   11          fld_len, fld_un
```

And re-test:

```
SELECT CONCAT(word1, word2) joined
FROM (
    SELECT w1.fld_un word1, w2.fld_un word2
    FROM j_un2 w1
    JOIN j_un2 w2 ON w1.fld_len = 8 - w2.fld_len
    WHERE w2.fld_len < 8
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 5) x;
```

The query took 30.3394 sec to return 5 rows.

Explain Plan:

```
id  select_type     table       type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY         <derived2>  ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL        NULL    5    
2   DERIVED         w2          range   bob             bob     4           NULL    4211    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED         w1          ref     bob             bob     4           func    527     Using where
```

---

**Update 3**

Ran without "order by rand()" and it ran in 0.0011 sec!

Comment: you're doing a cartesian join, basically, forcing the db consider 6200x6200 = 38,440,000 possible joinings. that's going to be slow no matter how you look at it, since indexes cannot be used in any way to speed up the process. and this is especially true since some of those words can never ever appear. `didgeridoo` is already longer than the limit, yet you're making the db join it against the other words, including itself.

Comment: Does this have to happen on the DB?  Is just fetching a huge list of words (limited by length) and processing them client-side an option?

Comment: do you have `my_word` index in `my_words` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a column, e.g. `word_length` that contains the length of the word, and add an index on the `word_length` column. Normally it would be poor design to include data that can be derived from another column, but in this case you need to break purity for performance sake. Then your query can use a `JOIN` condition using this column:

```
SELECT CONCAT(w1.my_word, w2.my_word) joined
FROM my_words w1
JOIN my_words w2 ON w1.word_length = 8 - w2.word_length
WHERE w2.word_length < 8
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

You can use `INSERT` and `UPDATE` triggers to fill in the `word_length` column automatically.

It might also be helpful to do the concatenation after filtering down to the 5 rows:

```
SELECT CONCAT(word1, word2) joined
FROM (
    SELECT w1.my_word word1, w2.my_word word2
    FROM my_words w1
    JOIN my_words w2 ON w1.word_length = 8 - w2.word_length
    WHERE w2.word_length < 8
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 5) x
```

Comment: Could this work with `ON LENGTH(w1.my_word) = 8 - LENGTH(w2.my_word) WHERE LENGTH(w2.my_word) < 8` instead of having to make another column?

Comment: It will work, but it will be slow, because there's no index on lengths.

Comment: @Barmar: Good answer. You should make clear, however, that there should be an an index on word_length for speed. (Which you did right now, implicitely with your comment :-)

Comment: It's in the first line of my answer: _and add an index on this column_.

Comment: @Barmar: Haha, I'm soo blind. Sorry.

Comment: @Muffled Cheese: This is a very good solution. There are other DBMS where you wouldn't even need the additional column, but use a function index instead (i.e. have a word column only, but the index is not on the word itself but on its length).

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for the suggestion. I did as you suggested, set up a new column called fld_len, set the value to be the length of the word, and then set up a new index on that. It now runs in 15 seconds?

Comment: Please add the `EXPLAIN` output to the question.

Comment: In case it's relevant, new index name = "un_len", column on index = "fld_len" and Index Type = not specified

Comment: See if my query with the subquery works better. This just defers the string concatenation, which could be slowing things down.

Comment: @Muffled Cheese: You can also try with an index on both fields: fld_len, fld_un. Thus you have a kind of pre-sorted table and the real table doesn't have to be accessed any longer.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I don't see how an index on the words helps, since nothing is searching or sorting the words.

Comment: @Barmar: The words are accessed in the SELECT clause. The DBMS could retrieve the words from the index itself rather than using the index to access the table.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for suggestions. I have done some more testing and updated my question (update 2) to show stats associated with updates and different indexes. Thanks

Comment: @Barmar - sorry for all the messages. When I removed "ORDER BY RAND()" the code runs in 0.0011 sec. I guess I need to find a more efficient way to get random records out then - I wondered if you know of any please? Thanks

Comment: There are quite a few questions on SO that answer how to get random results with MySQL. Try the search box.

Comment: Maybe instead of doing the randomization in MySQL, let the client application retrieve all the results and do its own randomization. How many results are there before selecting 5?

Answer (score 0):

If you can add another column and index to index the length of the word, you can do a join ON clause with the second Word length = desired length - first word length.

I think the real slow part here though is the rand().  You might get better results if you don't do that on the cartesian product, but on each table individually.  Although the results are different if you do that...